# Simple way to change console icon in a C++ .net console app?

Tags: .net, windows, console, icons

I have a C++ .NET console application for which I changed the icon that appears in the file manager. That's correct. But I also want the icon to be changed in the top bar of the console and in the task bar. It still let the old default icon.

I saw browsing SO that SetConsoleIcon() exists but it seems to be a Win32 API call???? Can't I have another way to do the job using .NET call(s)?

Thanks to tell me (an other users) if you have an idea about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible using 'pure' .NET, as from the application's point of view, Console has no icon.

The console having window with an icon is just an implementation detail.

Comment: So I understand that the "console" (the black box with the title bar) is a Windows implementation (in my case) and it is not "evil" to use Win32 API to change some of its features?

Comment: I included <windows.h>, then called SetConsoleIcon() and I got "SetConsoleIcon: identifier not found".

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE (for C++ VS2010)

1. Add resources file (rc) if you dont have any (by default `app.rc` should exist).
2. Add icon to resources
3. Set ID value for icon less then ID value of default icon (by default `app.ico` should exist).

Comment: Hello. There is no Application Tab. I read that about C# project??? I use VX2005 with a C++ project. I understand that what you suggest is very simple but it doesn't match what I see in my project properties.

Comment: @dom_beau see how you can change icon for CLR (or Win32) console application with C++

Comment: I have this in my .rc file: // Icon placed first or with lowest ID value becomes application icon

LANGUAGE 9, 4
#pragma code_page(1252)
1           ICON         "app.ico"

Comment: Sorry for the formatting... And of course app.ico is the right icon. But I just see it in the file manager, not in the console itself neither in the taskbar. And I don't start it from VS.

Comment: Did you verify `exe` file? Its icon should change after compilation of project

Comment: Well, I did not verify "explicitely" but I assumed it was OK since the icon associated to the .exe file changed in the file manager. Is it a naive assumption?

Comment: Maybe I didn't provide the right format for the icon? This would surprise me anyway... I guess Win 7 is intelligent enough to reformat the picture.